# Android service

Tags: android, android-notifications

In Android, I want to run a service which periodically connects to the server gets the message
and displays the message in full screen to the user irrespective of what the user is doing.

Should I be using the above approach or use GCM to deliver messages to the client device.

What component do I need to use to show a full screen message to the user ?
Notification requires the user to pull down the notification bar and select the notification. I want the message to appear right away in full screen on the user device.

Please let me know what component of android I should use to achieve the above step.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A GCM message should do. The additional information needed to show the message can be represented via JSON and parsed by your `GCMIntentService`. As long as the payload is within `4k` the messages will be delivered. The maximum retention time (at the moment) for a GCM message is 4 weeks. You might want to take that into consideration also.

As for displaying the message on the screen, it is possible to register broadcast receivers for an `Activity`. Alert the broadcast receiver and display the message if the activity is on the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

GCM is used for push notifications. For what you want to do, GCM is not needed at all if you simply want a service running executing some code at your set interval and polling your server. If you want to show a full screen message, simply create an activity and display that each time you execute the code in your interval. Now if you want that message to automatically disappear after a few seconds, then create a custom Toast message.

GCM will simply add another complexity layer that you don't need I think.